# Intersecting an arbitrary number of generic types

Tags: typescript, generics

I tried to write the following TypeScript code and the fact that it's kinda working is raising some questions. It's "kinda" working because the type of the constructed `"union"` property is indeed the union of the record values. Record keys are ignored.

```
export type Unificator<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = { [P in keyof T as "union"]: T[P] }["union"];

let u: Unificator<{
  a: { foo: "bar" },
  b: { bar: "baz" },
  c: { answer: 42 }
}>;

u = { foo: "bar" }; // Valid.
u = { bar: "baz" }; // Valid.
u = { answer: 42 }; // Valid.
```

The first three questions are:

- Is this a legitimate use of mapped types or am I doing something weird?
- Is there a more orthodox way to union an arbitrary number of types together?
- If the above code is indeed legit, is there a way to avoid that temporary *"union"* property?

But the most important question for me is another one:

- Is there a way to *"intersect"* an arbitrary number of types?

I want to do the following.

```
export type Intersector<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = /* HELP PLZ! */;

let i: Intersector<{
  a: { foo: "bar" },
  b: { bar: "baz" },
  c: { answer: 42 }
}>;

i = {
  foo: "bar",
  bar: "baz",
  answer: 42
}; // Valid.
```

Comment: Simplest way to create a union of object property types is probably `T[keyof T]` - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCSA7GwoGdgDGM0APACpyjYYAmucASodDSbjFAJYYDmANHACuGANYYIAdwwA+aXAC8cMgG0RwRBABmSgLoBYAFCGANsHicAXOiw58RUgG9DcOAEMrDuJogQrAIgAjVyg-OABfPmc4AI9o4P8ggC9QiKiCWNcMXAkcKwAWACZwwzDpAG5DQ04FOCcDF29fOEDgv0j6uKgE12T2l0zs3LhCkrK4AHpxuAA1V2NOGgA6IA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How we would normally do it is this:

```
type Unificator<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = T[keyof T];
```

You can find a small explanation [here](https://type-level-typescript.com/03-objects-and-records#the-keyof-keyword).

To intersect the members of the union together, we have to pull out our TypeScriptnomicon and [flip to page 50374908](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type):

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never
```

Then we can intersect the union from earlier:

```
type Intersector<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = UnionToIntersection<T[keyof T]>;
```

Also, the generic constraint `Record<string, unknown>` is not necessary in either of these, so you could omit those if you wish.

Comment: WOOOOOOOOAH! That's amazing! Thank you! Also, loved "TypeScriptnomicon" ahah. Seems a very good place to learn about the type system (even though I should probably go over the basics in the TypeScript manual, which I have not done for realsies yet). Thanks!

Comment: @damix911 This isn't exactly covered in the handbook, but it utilizes some of the concepts (particularly [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) and how [functions are contravariant](https://dmitripavlutin.com/typescript-covariance-contravariance/)).